# Sorting in groups in rpivottable

Tags: javascript, r, sorting, rpivottable

I've got a rpivottable generated with this code thanks to `rpivotTable` package in `R`:

```
library("rpivotTable")
library("dplyr")
library("reshape2")

dane <- melt(HairEyeColor)

rpivotTable(dane,
            rows = c("Hair", "Eye"),
            cols = c("Sex"),
            vals = "value",
            aggregatorName = "Integer Sum",
            locale = "en",
            rendererName = "Table With Subtotal",
            subtotals = TRUE)
```

which looks like that:

[image]

It is sorted alphabetically. And I would like to sort it in descending order using Total sum of values.

I can try sth like that:

```
library("rpivotTable")
library("dplyr")
library("reshape2")

dane <- melt(HairEyeColor)

sorter <- paste0("function(attr) {",
                 "var sortAs = $.pivotUtilities.sortAs;",
                 "if (attr == \"Eye\") { return sortAs([\"",
                 dane %>% group_by(Eye) %>% summarise(i = sum(value)) %>% arrange(-i) %>% .$Eye %>% paste(collapse = "\", \""),
                 "\"]); }",
                 "if (attr == \"Hair\") { return sortAs([\"",
                 dane %>% group_by(Hair) %>% summarise(i = sum(value)) %>% arrange(-i) %>% .$Hair %>% paste(collapse = "\", \""),
                 "\"]); }",
                 "}")

rpivotTable(dane,
            rows = c("Hair", "Eye"),
            cols = c("Sex"),
            vals = "value",
            aggregatorName = "Integer Sum",
            locale = "en",
            rendererName = "Table With Subtotal",
            subtotals = TRUE,
            sorters = sorter)
```

Than I get this:

[image]

and this is sorted by the 'outside' group. And I would like to have it sorted by both groups like here:

[image]

Is it possible in `rpivotTable` package?

Answer (score 0):

I might learn more from your question than you learn from my answer, because I liked your clever mixing of dplyr and JavaScript. To restate your problem, you are specifying a single Eye sort list in your sorter function, but you really want a different Eye sort list depending on the Hair grouping. So your Eye sorting list:

```
library("dplyr")
library("reshape2")

dane <- melt(HairEyeColor)
dane %>% group_by(Eye) %>% summarise(i = sum(value)) %>% 
   arrange(-i) %>% .$Eye %>% paste(collapse = "\", \"")
```

...has this output:

```
"Brown\", \"Blue\", \"Hazel\", \"Green"
```

... and that's the same sort order used within **each** Hair grouping. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56292094/is-there-any-way-to-set-the-sequence-of-the-column-of-pivot-in-pivottable-js/56299000#56299000).

I'm not an expert in pivottable, but to do what you want, I think the sorter function would have to handle two attributes like `[\"Hair\", \"Eye\"]`, not just one. I believe that a dplyr expression like this will get you to proper resulting two-dimensional list:

```
dane %>% group_by(Hair, Eye) %>% 
  summarise(hairEyeSum = sum(value)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange( desc(hairEyeSum)) %>% 
  group_by( Hair) %>% 
  mutate( hairSum = sum(hairEyeSum)) %>% 
  arrange( desc(hairSum), desc(hairEyeSum)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  transmute( hairEyeList = paste0( "[\"", Hair, "\",\"", Eye, "\"]"))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 1
   hairEyeList            
   <chr>                  
 1 "[\"Brown\",\"Brown\"]"
 2 "[\"Brown\",\"Blue\"]" 
 3 "[\"Brown\",\"Hazel\"]"
 4 "[\"Brown\",\"Green\"]"
 5 "[\"Blond\",\"Blue\"]" 
 6 "[\"Blond\",\"Green\"]"
 7 "[\"Blond\",\"Hazel\"]"
 8 "[\"Blond\",\"Brown\"]"
 9 "[\"Black\",\"Brown\"]"
10 "[\"Black\",\"Blue\"]" 
11 "[\"Black\",\"Hazel\"]"
12 "[\"Black\",\"Green\"]"
13 "[\"Red\",\"Brown\"]"  
14 "[\"Red\",\"Blue\"]"   
15 "[\"Red\",\"Hazel\"]"  
16 "[\"Red\",\"Green\"]"
```

But I came up short of getting the sorter function working.