# Is there any way to set the sequence of the column of pivot in pivottable.js?

Tags: javascript, pivottable.js

I want to create the pivot table in my website. So I've used the `pivottable.js` for creating the pivot table.

I'm able to create the pivot table using the following JS, but not able to set the sequence of the column.

following code is used to generate the pivot table.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var sum = $.pivotUtilities.aggregatorTemplates.sum;
  var numberFormat = $.pivotUtilities.numberFormat;
  var intFormat = numberFormat({digitsAfterDecimal: 0});
    $("#raw_data_op").pivot(
        [
            ["id","mycount","type","date"],
            ["Name1","10","Emp1","1/1/2010"],
            ["Name1","13","Emp2","1/1/2010"],
            ["Name1","14","Emp1","1/2/2010"],
            ["Name1","10","Emp2","1/2/2010"],
            ["Name1","14","Emp1","1/3/2010"],
            ["Name1","12","Emp2","1/3/2010"],
            ["Name2","11","Emp1","1/1/2010"],
            ["Name2","13","Emp2","1/1/2010"],
            ["Name2","18","Emp1","1/2/2010"],
            ["Name2","10","Emp2","1/2/2010"],
            ["Name2","9","Emp1","1/3/2010"],
            ["Name2","17","Emp2","1/3/2010"],
            ["Name3","9","Emp1","1/1/2010"],
            ["Name3","0","Emp2","1/1/2010"],
            ["Name3","10","Emp1","1/2/2010"],
            ["Name3","12","Emp2","1/2/2010"],
            ["Name3","19","Emp1","1/3/2010"],
            ["Name3","10","Emp2","1/3/2010"],
        ], {
            rows: ["id"],
            cols: ["date","type"],
            aggregator: sum(intFormat)(["mycount"])
        });
});
```

Current Result:-

[image: Current Result]

Instead of **Emp1**, can we get **Emp2** first in the column sequence ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `sorters` configuration option. Something like

```
sorters: {"type": $.pivotUtilities.sortAs(["Emp2", "Emp1"])}
```

Or in general you can just pass in any old comparator:

```
sorters: {"type": function(a,b){ return string_a.localeCompare(string_b) }
```